# Recieve image from IOS mknetwork to php server

Tags: php, ios, image-uploading, mknetworkengine

I am sending image through MKnetwork to php server... on php side the image is recieved in $_POST instead of $_FILES... here is my code from ios side

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImgPath];// fullpath contains the path of image
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.0);

MKNetworkEngine *engine=[[MKNetworkEngine alloc]initWithHostName:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:imageData forKey:@"uploadedfile"];
NSString *url=@"http://ilogiks.co.uk/demo/image/upload.php";
MKNetworkOperation *op=[engine operationWithURLString:url params:dict httpMethod:@"POST"];
```

From php side

```
echo "POST";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "FILES";
var_dump($_FILES);
```

$_FILES show empty image and $_POST show following response

```
array(1){
["uploadedfile"]=>
string(50523) "<ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001.............
```

I want image to be recieved in $_FILES so that i can save it or if there is an other solution possible? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mknetwork is sending image in hex format through post so you need to receive it from post and write it in a new file in following format

```
$img = $_POST['uploadedfile'];
$img = str_replace("<","",$img);
$img = str_replace(">","",$img);
$img = str_replace(" ","",$img);
$img = pack("H*", $img);
$file = "img.png";
$f = fopen($file,'wb');
fwrite($f, $img);
fclose($f);
```